# Intellij IDEA 13 code completion popup disappears on documentation popup appearing

Tags: intellij-idea

Such behavior was not all the time. Previously it was OK, and as far as I remember documentation popup looked like a code completion popup, but now it appears like a panel and traps keyboard focus when it appears. Previously I was able to switch between code completion list elements seeing their documentation. What should I do to get normal behavior back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `Pinned Mode` was enabled for `Documentation` panel. Turning off `Pinned Mode` deals with a problem.

Comment: How can I do that when it disappears instantly ?

Comment: @momo could you clarify, what disappears in your case? Does you situation corresponds with mine?

Comment: I have a popup for the documentation and I accidantely tested to set it as a floating more or unpinned mode, so it pops out, but looses focus immediately after adn disappears. So i am unable to pin it back on :(

Comment: @momo in the Documentation window right click on the first line after title bar and select «Close All» or «Close View» (if only one documentation opened)

Comment: I was struggling with same issue for quite some time. @momo last comment did the trick! :)

Answer (score 14):

Try to invalidate caches: File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: ahh, this actually helped. code completion is back!

Comment: Ah, good ol' invalidate caches.

Answer (score 5):

I had to turn this off:
`Hide navigation popups on focus loss`

[image]

Comment: that exactly solved my problem with flickering autocompletion popup window. many thanks mate.